# How to Truncate a word which is having unicode characters without breaking the unicode?

Tags: php, utf-8, unicode-string

I am having a word like "Stefan Äöüéèêë". I want to truncate this string after 20 characters...but it is giving me like Stefan Äöüéèê� . 
I am using following code for this.

```
$string = "Stefan Äöüéèêë";
if(strlen($string) > 20){
       $string = substr($string, 0, 20) . '...';      
}
```

How can I get string which is safely truncated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the multibyte version of it:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-substr.php

Further more here is a list of unicode unsafe methods that is quite handy: http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8

Note: strlen does return the wrong value

Comment: @samuel if you find length after utf8_decode then it will give right result :)

Answer (score 1):

try this friend , if you decode the string then it will give proper length of string.

```
$string = "Stefan Äöüéèêë";
$string= utf8_decode($string);
echo strlen($string);
if(strlen($string) > 10){
    $string = mb_substr($string, 0, 10);   
}
echo $string;
```

Comment: Only you cannot use `strlen()` because that gives you the total number of bytes, not characters. Use `mb_strlen()` instead.